# Mapping list elements into their positions (Python)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of URLs. (We can assume that a given URL is met in the list no more than once.)

I need a fast way to determine which of two URLs is before in the list.

I think, I should create the dict from URL to its position in the list.

What is the easy way (without writing a `for` loop with manual increasing of the counter) to map elements of a list into their positions in the list?

The best thing I conceived is:

```
order = {}
i = 0
for item in list:
    order[item] = i
    i += 1
```

Now to check if `url1` is before `url2`, I check `order[url1] < order[url2]`.

Can this code be shortened?

Comment: @RoadRunner "We can assume that a given URL is met in the list no more than once."

Comment: What you are looking for is [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Comment: `dict(map(reversed, enumerate(urls)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This creates your `order`

```
order = {k: v for v, k in enumerate(list)}
```

Example:

```
L = list('abc')
```

Your version:

```
order1 = {}
i = 0
for item in L:
    order1[item] = i
    i += 1
print(order1)
```

My version:

```
order2 = {k: v for v, k in enumerate(L)}
print(order2)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}
{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}
```

Better don't use `list`for your variable name because it is a built-in.

[enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) provides an iterate that gives you the index and the value for each iteration through your list.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know which comes first for a specific pair of items, you can use the `index` method on the list:

```
a = ['cat', 'dog', 'fish']

a.index('cat') < a.index('dog') # True
a.index('fish') < a.index('dog') # False
```

Comment: This would have to traverse the list twice for each comparison. Whereas OP's dictionary index mapping only requires one traversal overall.

Comment: The original question isn't clear on the requirement: `determine which of two URLs is before in the list.` If the urls are coming from outside the list, then this is a perfectly good approach.